# How can I avoid hardcoding the database connection password?

Tags: php, database, password-protection

I am working on a school-project (writing a website) and I ran into the problem of providing the password for the connection to our database. Because of our Open-Source license we have to publish the sourcecode but that would mean that everyone could connect to the database and see tha data.

Currently our connection (a php file) looks like this:

```
$host="************";
$password="************";
$this->conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname).mysqli_connect_error());
```

Now my question is: how can i provide the password to connect to the database without needing to write `$password=...` ?

Comment: `$password = 'ENTER YOUR PASSWORD HERE";` readme.txt: `"Enter your database credentials in the dbconfig.php file"` This is a really weird question

Comment: You cannot. but in mysql you can restrict the hosts from where the connection is valid. You allow only trusted connections. Another option is you remove the actual connection details before publishing the code.

Comment: Write the password to a flat file (e.g. xyz.ini) and read it in. Hand-out the code with an empty or dummy password, the user of the software has to change anyway. You also could import the other parameters (host, username, database name) like this.

Comment: @hherger you should post that as an answer

Comment: Environment variables, `include`ing or otherwise reading a config file on disk, implicit configuration in php.ini or such... many many options.

Comment: Setup a database proxy on the localhost where this should be configured first. Your application could connect password-less to the proxy. Or: Use a generated hardware ID as a password, set this up once. Or: as everyone is commenting: dont bother as long as it is NOT in your versioning system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here's the one with the *ini* file:

### xxx.php

```
<?php

    $db_params = parse_ini_file( dirname(__FILE__).'/db_params.ini', false );

    // .....

    $this->conn = new mysqli($db_params['host'], $db_params['user'], $db_params['password'], $db_params['dbname'], $db_params['port'], $db_params['socket']).mysqli_connect_error());

    // ...

?>
```

### db_params.ini

```
host=mysql.example.com
port=3306
socket=
user=testuser
password=myPasswort
dbname=myDatabase
```

Comment: also make sure you do `echo db_params.ini > .gitignore` ;) (or the equivalent for your VCS)

Comment: Right @hd. Also, if you deliver the software together with a setup script, it would be a good idea to init the _db\_params.ini_ file there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single file to contain your configuration variables and exclude this file when sharing your code.

For example:

```
require_once('config.php');
$this->conn = new mysqli($config['db']['host'], $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['pass'], $config['db']['dbname']);
```

The `config.php` file would include:

```
$config['db']['username'] = 'user';
$config['db']['password'] = 'pass';
...
```

You could/should expand this to include the host, port, database name etc.