# How to avoid hard coded database credentials in code

Tags: java, database

I've been searching for a way to avoid hard coding my database credentials into my code base (mainly written in Java), but I haven't found many solutions. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509181/replacing-hard-coded-credentials) post where they said a one way hash could be the answer. Is there another way of securely connecting to a database without running into the risk of someone decompiling your code?

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for code, rather a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you can used spring boot application, then you can configure using cloud config method. I have added some postgresql db connection details for your further reference. Please refer following link for spring boot cloud config. [spring_cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config)

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://{{db_url}}:5432/{{db_name}}
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.maxActive=3
spring.datasource.maxIdle=3
spring.datasource.minIdle=2
spring.datasource.initialSize=2
spring.datasource.removeAbandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=3
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load a config file in your code. Define some kind of file, such as JSON or XML, and define all of your configurations in there. You could point to the file as a command line argument, or just hardcode the file path.

Here's a post talking about parsing JSON config in Java:
[How to read json file into java with simple JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926353/how-to-read-json-file-into-java-with-simple-json-library)

Comment: If they can decompile the application to get credentials then shipping an application with a file containing credentials doesn't seem much better.

Comment: The file wouldn't be compiled. If none is provided, the program wouldn't start.

Comment: So you'd ship an uncompiled file... I don't understand how this solves anything at all. The OP is stating that decompiling the code is the issue: this means we're not talking about a web app (or at least not a remote web app). If they can decompile the code it means it's local. If it's local an external file with credentials has the exact same issue as the code.

Comment: Makes sense. I was thinking more along the lines of something being deployed.

Comment: Yea this would be a simple desktop application, so people would be able to decompile the code and possibly look at any config file that are compiled with the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to these post. They are basically just saying to either hash, store it in a property file or use an API. Some of the posts are not merely on Java but you can get ideas from them.

> [How can I avoid hardcoding the database connection password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156847/how-can-i-avoid-hardcoding-the-database-connection-password)
>   https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36076/how-to-avoid-scripts-with-hardcoded-password
>   https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1087423/Simplest-Way-to-Avoid-Hardcoding-of-the-Confidenti

Answer (score 1):

The solution in our team, database as a service,other application use it's API to get database credentials,the request contains simple credentials like application name.

Comment: How would I go about making a simple API of that sort? Are there any resources you know of?

Comment: @justanotherguy as far as I know there is no library for this,but create a API for this is simple,you can create a rest api(database as server).

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51268633/3957754

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to avoid hard code values in your source code:

- Properties using Advanced Platforms
- Properties from Environment variables
- Properties from SCM
- Properties from File System

More details here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51268633/3957754